# Nodejs socket.io server options

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx

I have a [NodeJS socket.io](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) server with the following declaration:

```
const express = require("express");
const expressApp = express();
const server = http.createServer(expressApp);

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    pingInterval: 60000,
    pingTimeout: 10000
});
```

The ping interval is the time the server sends a ping packet to the client and the ping timeout is the time to disconnect the connection if a ping reply is not received in that duration.

The socket.io server sits behind a NGINX server which is already configured to allow socket.io connections using the recommended NGINX configuration: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

In the [client](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html), it is running python and uses this code to make connection to the server. The client connects once and does not disconnect unless the client is restarted or exited. The client is kept online all the time.

```
sio.connect(serverUrl + '/socket.io/')
```

Now the main problem is that after every minute, the client gets disconnected and connected. This is not my original intention. The original purpose was to remove dead client connections.

Why is the client disconnected and connecting every [pingInterval] given that it is always online?

[image]

Comment: Did you try lowering the pingInterval?  You've picked a pretty long interval.  Some piece of network infrastructure may be decided that this is a dead connection and it's killing it.

Comment: And, what are the relevant timeouts on nginx for inactive connections?

Comment: @jfriend00 I lowered down the pingInterval to 10s and it seems to be working now. No more unintended disconnect and reconnect. For the nginx settings, i did not specify and timeouts. I used similar settings as shown below:

location /wsapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://wsbackend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}

Answer (score 0):

In the client you have to use `forceNew: true`

```
sio.connect(serverUrl + '/socket.io/',{ forceNew: true});
```

By default, a single connection is used when connecting to different namespaces (to minimize resources).This behavior can be disabled with the forceNew option.

[Socket Client Reference](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

Comment: What does this have to do with sockets getting closed?

Comment: @jfriend00 Whenever more than single connection, it disconnects the previous connection. So to force it forceNew:true is used.

Comment: Disconnects the previous connection when what happens?  I've never had to use `forceNew` and never had a problem like this.